# Is there an alternative for game server which works like Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: server, cloud, cloud-hosting

I was really satisfied by the billing structure of cloud functions. They only charge during the runtime of a function based on how much resources it consumes. I am looking for a similar solution for my game servers.

I checked various cloud hosting options like VMs but all providers like digital ocean, google, amazon etc. charge even when there is no load on VM (and I completely understand the reason for that).

I am looking for an option where I can deploy my game server and will charge me only when it will consume resources(based on how much resources it consume) and won't charge (or a minimal charge) when the server is idle. It's like it will auto scale based on the current load.

Thankyou in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Squids.io(https://squids.io/), a fully managed database service provider allows you to power off when your server is idle, and you can restart it at anytime of your choice. Plus, it charges you no management fees.